# Generate .msi file from .vdproj file?

Tags: c#

In my source code I am having sample.vdproj file.But in guidelines they asked to build sample.msi.how to generate .msi files from .vdproj file?it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Run `devenv.exe` against your vdproj:

```
devenv.exe /build Release_or_other_conf yourfile.vdproj
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of your `vdproj` file, building it will generate either an [installation package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) (MSI) or a [merge module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369820.aspx) (MSM).

So, try to build it in Visual Studio and check its output directory. See [Setup and Deployment Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx) on MSDN for an overview.

Comment: New link for "Setup and Deployment Projects [Setup and Deployment Projects][1] [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t(v=vs.80).aspx